Crash ControlOnExit when clicking on another ContentControl
I'm learning how to develop macros with vba to automate the filling in of a document at work.I'm getting the hang of it, even though I'm aware that it's certainly not optimised but I'm having a problem with a contentcontrolonexit event.
This is how it works:
we have 6 criteria for which the user must enter a number of occurrences, between 1 and 10, in the Occurrences contentcontrol. On exiting this contentcontrol, the ContentControlOnExit event is launched and activates 4 procedures. Everything works perfectly when the user exits the contentcontrol by clicking on an empty space in the document or a text or still image. However, if they click on the Image contentcontrol (to the left), 3 procedures work well but the "addBorders" procedure crashes and the document is closed.
visual extract of the document
The purpose of this procedure is to frame the image content control with a green border (if occurrences <4) or a red border (if occurrences >= 4).
Here are the code extracts for the ContentControlOnExit and addBorders events.
Private Sub Document_ContentControlOnExit(ByVal CC As ContentControl, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim i As Integer
Dim ccNb, ccIndice, ccTT_V, ccTT_NV As Integer
Dim ccCritRisk As String

'----------------------If you change the number of occurrences of a criterion--------------------
If Left(CC.Tag, 7) = "Critère" Then

    CC.SetPlaceholderText , , "Occurences"
    ccIndice = CInt(Right(CC.Tag, 1)) 'the criterion index is retrieved
    
    If CC.ShowingPlaceholderText = False Then 'if the number of occurrences is filled in
        ccNb = CInt(CC.Range.Text) 'the number of occurences is retrieved
        
        'Pour le critère modifié:
        selectComment ccNb, ccIndice, critArray 'select and fill the comment on the right - WORKS WELL EVERYTIME
        occuCount 'fill the introduction text - WORKS WELL EVERYTIME
        addBorders ccNb, ccIndice 'add the border to the image of the criterion
        tableFill ccNb, ccIndice 'fill the table on first page -WORKS WELL EVERYTIME
     Else
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Com" & CStr(ccIndice))(1).SetPlaceholderText , , "Commentaire automatique"
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Com" & CStr(ccIndice))(1).Range.Text = PlaceholderText
     End If

Else
'Other things done with other contentcontrol in the document, not linked to the problem
End If
End Sub

Sub addBorders(ccNb, ccIndice)

If ccNb > 10 Then
    MsgBox ("Le nombre " & ccNb & " est trop élevé")
    Exit Sub
Else
    If ccNb < 4 Then
        With ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Image" & CStr(ccIndice))(1).Range
            With .Borders(wdBorderLeft)
                    .LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
                    .LineWidth = wdLineWidth300pt
                    .Color = RGB(71, 212, 89)
            End With
        End With
    Else 'on met commentaire négatif et bordure rouge
        With ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Image" & CStr(ccIndice))(1).Range
            With .Borders(wdBorderLeft)
                    .LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
                    .LineWidth = wdLineWidth300pt
                    .Color = RGB(200, 0, 0)
            End With
        End With
    End If
End If


End Sub

The addBorders procedure is the only one that involves selecting the contentcontrolImage on which the user has potentially clicked (to exit the Occurences contentcontrol). I don't think it's possible to select this already selected contentcontrol.
I tried changing the position of the cursor before running addBorders to make sure it wasn't on the image but that didn't work. I don't know what else to do...
Technically, it's not a problem because I'll just have to explain to my colleagues to click on an empty space after entering the number of occurrences, but it's restrictive and not really intuitive. I'd like the user to be "free to move" between the Occurences and Images contentcontrols.
If anyone has any ideas on how to solve the problem, thank you for your help. i can provide more details if necessary.

I see similar problems here. Word just does not seem to like it when you change certain things in a ContentControl Event. (It does not seem to object if you change the image control's Tag, for example).
I suppose the easiest way to avoid this might be to find some visual property that you can change during the Event and use that instead. But another thing that can work is to run the routine asynchronously, i.e. so that the addBorders method is not called from the Event code. I do not particularly like it but it is probably worth trying.
At the simplest level, you modify the method so that you do not have to supply it with parameter values (e.g. make the parameter values module-level values if the addBorders method is in the same module as the Event handler), and use Application.Timer to schedule the method at the end of the Event code.
e.g.
' Put the parameter values in module-level variables
' NB, "Dim ccNb, ccIndice As Integer" actually declares ccNb as an Object, not an Integer. It's a VB oddity. Instead, you can either use
' Dim ccNb As Integer, ccIndice As Integer
' or separate them out...
Dim ccNb As Integer
Dim ccIndice As Integer
Private Sub Document_ContentControlOnExit(ByVal CC As ContentControl, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim i As Integer
Dim ccTT_V As Integer
Dim ccTT_NV As Integer
Dim ccCritRisk As String

'----------------------If you change the number of occurrences of a criterion--------------------
If Left(CC.Tag, 7) = "Critère" Then

    CC.SetPlaceholderText , , "Occurences"
    ccIndice = CInt(Right(CC.Tag, 1)) 'the criterion index is retrieved
    
    If CC.ShowingPlaceholderText = False Then 'if the number of occurrences is filled in
        ccNb = CInt(CC.Range.Text) 'the number of occurences is retrieved
        
        'Pour le critère modifié:
        selectComment ccNb, ccIndice, critArray 'select and fill the comment on the right - WORKS WELL EVERYTIME
        occuCount 'fill the introduction text - WORKS WELL EVERYTIME
        tableFill ccNb, ccIndice 'fill the table on first page -WORKS WELL EVERYTIME
     Else
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Com" & CStr(ccIndice))(1).SetPlaceholderText , , "Commentaire automatique"
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Com" & CStr(ccIndice))(1).Range.Text = PlaceholderText
     End If

Else
'Other things done with other contentcontrol in the document, not linked to the problem
End If

' DOn't use "Now" or Time to get the time, as it returns the time rounded to a whole second, whereas Timer has something like 0.01s resolution. I've added 0.1s - maybe even 0.01 is always reliable (and if so, would likely look less sluggish)
Application.OnTime  Date + (Timer + 0.1) / 86400#, "addBorders" 

End Sub

Sub addBorders()

If CCNB > 10 Then
    MsgBox ("Le nombre " & CCNB & " est trop élevé")
    Exit Sub
Else
    If CCNB < 4 Then
      With ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Image" & CStr(CCINDICE))(1).Range
           With .Borders(wdBorderLeft)
                    .LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
                    .LineWidth = wdLineWidth300pt
                    .Color = RGB(71, 212, 89)
            End With
        End With
    Else 'on met commentaire négatif et bordure rouge
        With ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Image" & CStr(CCINDICE))(1).Range
            With .Borders(wdBorderLeft)
                    .LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
                    .LineWidth = wdLineWidth300pt
                    .Color = RGB(200, 0, 0)
            End With
        End With
    End If
End If


End Sub

I would be surprised if a search did not find better-tested ways to do this.

Hello @jonsson
your solution may not be the best one but it was definitely worth a try. With a little modification of my code, it works !
Thanks a lot
